Can’t update system with “sudo apt update” on Ubuntu 22.04
root@jizpi:/home/jizpi# sudo apt update
Ign:1 https://https//launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/apt stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:3 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease [20.0 kB]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:8 https://example.com/apt stable InRelease
Ign:1 https://https//launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/apt stable InRelease
Err:9 https://example.com/apt stable Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.184.216.34 443]
Ign:1 https://https//launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/apt stable InRelease
Err:1 https://https//launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/apt stable InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'https'
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://example.com/apt stable Release' does not have a Relea                                                                                                             se file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa                                                                                                             bled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta                                                                                                             ils.


Your package system is broken because your software sources are a mess. example.com? Really? trusty, bionic, jammy...

Not sure why you are using ppa’s from different versions of Ubuntu. If you are on jammy, you should be using jammy ppa’s, not trusty or bionic.
